# Unable to log $request_body in nginx log

Tags: nginx

I'm having some trouble getting nginx to conditionally log the request body. I don't want to log login credentials, and accordingly have included a map that correctly triggers when the URI is/is not the login URI. There seem to be a number of similar posts suggesting using

- `client_body_in_single_buffer on`
- `fastcgi_pass php_cgi`
- `echo_read_request_body`

but none of those seem to help. Any ideas? Below is the current configuration.

```
map $request_uri $log_body {

  ~/login 0;
  default 1;
}

log_format filter '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  '"$request" $status $request_time $upstream_response_time "$scrubbed_request"';

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/site.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/site.log filter;

  location /branch/dev/v2/ {

    set $scrubbed_request 'NOT LOGGED';
    if ($log_body) {
      set $scrubbed_request $request_body;
    }   
    rewrite /branch/dev/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
  location /branch/dev/ {
    rewrite /branch/dev/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001;
  }
}
```

Note that if `$scrubbed_request` is replaced with `$request_body` in the log_format line, we do capture all request bodies. This makes me think that the `set` statement is somehow consuming the `request_body` in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to [read the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_body):

> The variable’s value is made available in locations processed by the proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, and scgi_pass directives when the request body was read to a [memory buffer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size) .

As you can see, you have to configure your `client_body_buffer_size` big enough to store the whole body in memory.

You also don't need the `set` statements, you can use [the `if` parameter of `access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) and different formats.

Comment: How would upping `client_body_in_single_buffer` help if my request body was only a small string like `abcdef`? It'd seem like that string should easily fit into the 16K buffer the docs are saying is provisioned for 64 bit instances. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Justin You haven't mentioned how big your request body is. So, the size is ok, then you should avoid using `set`. The `set` directive is part of the rewrite module, which works before nginx starts reading body.